# How do I convert global coordinates to local?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have created some simple drag and drop. (There's some junk in the code that seems like it ought to be useful.)

Html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
   var el = document.getElementById('target');
   var mover = false,
       x, y, posx, posy, first = true;
   el.onmousedown = function () {
       mover = true;
   };
   document.onmouseup = function () {
       mover = false;
       first = false;
   };
   document.onmousemove = function (e) {
       if (mover) {
           e = e || window.event;
           var target = e.srcElement || e.target;

           var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
           if (first) {
               first = false;
               x = (getMouseCoordinates(e).x - rect.left);
               y = (getMouseCoordinates(e).y - rect.top);
           }

           posx = getMouseCoordinates(e).x;// - x;
           posy = getMouseCoordinates(e).y;// - y;

           el.style.left = posx + 'px';
           el.style.top = posy + 'px';
       }
   };


   function getMouseCoordinates(e) {
       e = e || window.event;

       var pageX = e.pageX;
       var pageY = e.pageY;
       if (pageX === undefined) {
           pageX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
           pageY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
       }

       return {
           x: pageX,
           y: pageY
       }
   }
```

CSS:

```
#target {
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffc;
    position: absolute;
}
#container {
    left: 30px;
    top:30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YGzm6/

The problem is that the draggable is inside a container that is positioned. So when I position the draggable with the mouse's global co-ordinates, the draggable is actually being positioned relative to its non global container.

So how do I translate the co-ordinates such that the draggable doesn't jump about? Surely I need to know the offset of the parent container?

Comment: You could use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the offset position of the container element. See your code, you're already using the same to get the offset position of the draggable element.

Comment: I guess so. I wonder if getting a parent element is cross-browser dependable. My idea is to avoid this all together and clone the draggable at the root and drag that instead.

Comment: if you use jquery, `offset()` method returns left and top of an element relative to document.

Comment: Otherwise loop until the `offsetParent` of the parent elements is not null adding the `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft`.

Comment: check my answer for the above approach

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = 0, y = 0;
var element = document.getElementById('container');

do {
    x += element.offsetLeft;
    y += element.offsetTop;
}
while (element = element.offsetParent);
```

Comment: See this article for the low-down on this method... http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/